# Firefox can't download images

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, downloads

I cannot download images in Firefox. I right click them, select save image as, select the location, and then it won't even start downloading; it will stay at 0% for hours and never really start, but if I attempt to close the browser, even 10 hours after it will say "downloads are in progress, are you sure you want to quit" or similar.

Chrome doesn't have the same issue, it works perfectly.

Also, Firefox didn't start showing this behaviour until a couple of weeks ago and I have been using Ubuntu for years. I cannot remember any changes I made that could have triggered it.

Any advice?

Comment: Does this happen with every website? Could you name at least a few websites that this happens on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Worked for me.

Go to **Help** Menu > **Troubleshooting information** > click **Reset firefox**.